# redirect subdomain but it doesn't work with extra characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain, cpanel

I'm trying to make a subdomain to redirect to another domain, but it only works if there are no extra characters in it. Like for example **n1.domain.com** redirect to **domain2.com**.
When I tried adding characters like **n1.domain.com/word** it gave me a "404 not found" error. I'm trying to make the **n1.domain.com/word** into **domain2.com/word**.
I'm using cPanel by the way.

Comment: On question, put your htaccess for general information. Cpanel it's not important. It's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I used the cloudflare pagerules, works like what I was looking for.